# Unable to convert dataframe to parquet, TypeError

Tags: pandas, pyarrow

I was trying to convert a data frame to a parquet file. But I faced the following error.

```
result = pa.array(col, type=type_, from_pandas=True, safe=safe)
  File "pyarrow\array.pxi", line 265, in pyarrow.lib.array
  File "pyarrow\array.pxi", line 80, in pyarrow.lib._ndarray_to_array
  File "pyarrow\error.pxi", line 107, in pyarrow.lib.check_status
pyarrow.lib.ArrowTypeError: ('Expected a string or bytes dtype, got float64', 'Conversion failed for column NOTES with type float64')
```

The column type is varchar, so this it converts to str. But there are a few numeric values in the records of that column, and I am doubtful that the data frame parses them as float. Thus, while converting to parquet, it returns a float value that produces an error.

Is there a way to convert the values of these records to str format.

> I tried using astype(str) but didn't work.

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly didn't work when using `astype(str)` ? Got the same error? Also, are you able to provide a small reproducible example?

Comment: http://github.com/wesm/feather/issues/349

Comment: What you link to actually mentions `astype(str)` as a work-around.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, *parquet* expects a single type per column. To fix a case like above *(i.e. mixed value types)*, convert it to Pandas 'string' like this:

```
df['NOTES'] = df['NOTES'].astype('string') 
# & then ... df.to_parquet(...)
```

Comment: Instead of 'string' it has to be 'str' like:
`df['NOTES'] = df['NOTES'].astype('str')`

Comment: It will convert None to 'None'.