# I can't convert df to parquet by data type error

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, parquet

I'm trying to convert a pandas dataframe to parquet, but I'm getting an error "Exptected bytes, got a 'int' object", 'Conversion failed for column xxxxxxxx with type object')
This table in Excel has numbers and strings, it is like dtype 'object', even so it gives error. I've tried df['xxxxxxxx'].astype(str), df['xxxxxxxx'].astype('data_type'), but none of them work.
I tried do convert to parquet with AWS Wrangler and Pyarrow

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! To ask about errors, please include your code as a [mre] and always include the full trackback. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64364129/unable-to-convert-dataframe-to-parquet-typeerror)

A general type of the column could work. So try:

```
df['xxxxxxxx'] = df['xxxxxxxx'].astype(str)
df.to_parquet(path)
```

However, this is not a good practice as this will hide the type error, you should consider fixing the type of the column by separating data or be aware that this columnhas different types. Pandas has a warning included for these type of errors:

```
   Columns (# of column) have mixed types. Specify dtype option on import or set low_memory=False.
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try :

```
df['xxxxxxxx'] = df['xxxxxxxx'].astype(bytes)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Setting `engine='fastparquet'` argument for the `to_parquet` method helped me.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error while saving my pandas dataframe to paraquet using aws wrangler.
This happened in my case when first few rows of a column were of `datetime` type, and remaining rows below were of sting type. I used this to check for columns that have different datatypes within them.

```
for c in range(df.shape[1]):
    for i in range(df.shape[0]):
        if(type(df.iloc[0,c])!=type(df.iloc[i,c])): 
            print("difference found in cell ", i,c)
            print("column name =", df.columns[c])
            break
            
# if you get difference for nan types (float) ignore that
```

Then convert the all the rows of identified columns to one single datatype.